Verification of Zeta Distribution PMF
This question asks to verify that the Zeta distribution is indeed a PMF by summing the probabilities. This is given by:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n^s}\times \frac{1}{\zeta(s)} \right) 
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n^s}\times \frac{1}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}} \right) $$
and then the next step in the video is that it is one.
I am seem to be missing something "obvious" here, but it is not clear to me. I think it is a nested summation, and hence the inside summation cannot be "pulled out". Please help.

It is "obvious": if each of the probabilities is proportional to $\frac1{n^s}$ then they are each equal to $\dfrac{\frac1{n^s}}{\sum_n \frac1{n^s}}$ and the denominator is by definition the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$

I realised this is because $\zeta(s)$ is independent of s, and hence that term moves out of the summation, leaving
$$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\times\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{n^s}= \frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(s)} =1$$
